# Raspberry Pi as basis for commercial device?

Tags: development, raspberry-pi

I am thinking of using a Raspberry Pi as the basis of an electronics project that I am working on, and plan to eventually sell to the public. I want to use the Raspberry Pi in order to reduce the development time and development complexity of the device. As a general statement am I better off taking the time, developing an ARM based system that runs Android, or should I just use the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I would suggest to wait some time before accepting an answer. Questions with an accepted answer get fewer new answers, which might have been interesting too. You accepted before Europe was even awake. Give it a day or so, or at least till you got 3 or 4 answers.

Comment: @stevenvh By the time tomorrow rolls around, I will never get to picking an answer. I have amazing ADD skills. (and I am getting around to posting this reply 6 months after your comment...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably say that the Raspberry Pi would be great to test everything and make sure your project will work. Of course, nothing's stopping you from using it too but if you want to sell to the public, the Raspberry Pi might be hard to get enough of. Plus, it would probably cost more because of the added functionality you won't need, and not fit an ideal form factor for your project. You would have to design your project around the computer controlling it (Raspberry Pi) instead of the other way around.

It would help a little more if we knew the nature of your project, but I understand that may be confidential.

Comment: You are correct, the project specifics are confidential at this time, but I can tell you that the final result will be ultra thin. Taking into consideration of what you said, and some good points that I had not thought about, I think it will better to go the route of an ARM SoC. Do you know any good ones out there?

Comment: Sounds good. Unfortunately, I am quite new to electronics so I don't want to mislead you with suggestions I cannot properly justify. But there are brilliant people here who will soon chime in with much better answers, so you may also want to wait before selecting mine as the best :-) Good luck with your project!

Comment: Realistic selection is going to depend on your performance, resource, and I/O needs.  A small arm platform can be designed and fabricated in a few hours, but something the complexity of a pi or beagle would involve substantial effort and expense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an ARM SoC, you could take a look at ARM PSoC5 from cypress,  http://www.cypress.com/?id=2233 . They have a nice IDE, it comes with GCC compiler. They can have some EMI sensibility problems, i have tested it with a nonstandard test. Good luck with your project!

Comment: EMI issues doesn't sound good for something you want to use in a commercial device :-(